# Java command line argument issue

Tags: java

Im trying to test command line arguments in Java.  I am typing the name of my program then -c, like below

```
java myprogram -c
```

here is my code

```
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    System.out.println(args.length);
    if (args[0]== "-c")
        System.out.println("YES");
```

when I run the program I get:

```
-c
1
```

but not the YES.... can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `if (args.length > 0 && "-c".equals(args[0])) {...}`

Comment: == is for checking if two objects are the same, use .equals